# Using grad cam with 2 inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model with 2 inputs, image and metadata. I want to do the Grad_Cam method to see which features are being selected in the image but I can't seem to do it. I use the Gram_cad functions of the keras examples, https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/. This is my model:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
resnet50 (Functional)           (None, 7, 7, 2048)   23587712    input_8[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_9 (InputLayer)            [(None, 28)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_2 (Glo (None, 2048)         0           resnet50[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 2048)         59392       input_9[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multiply_2 (Multiply)           (None, 2048)         0           global_average_pooling2d_2[0][0] 
                                                                 dense_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 8)            16392       multiply_2[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,663,496
Trainable params: 23,610,376
Non-trainable params: 53,120
```

When I try to run the code below the error `*** AssertionError: Could not compute output KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2048), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='multiply_2/mul:0', description="created by layer 'multiply_2'")` appears.

```
preds = flat_model.predict([image,metadata]) 
i = np.argmax(preds[0])

# Generate class activation heatmap
heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(image, flat_model, "multiply_2")
```

If I change the layer name to "resnet50" a different error appears: `*** ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_7'), name='input_7', description="created by layer 'input_7'") at layer "conv1_pad". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []`~´

What am I doing wrong? Is it impossible to do this method since it has 2 inputs?